# How to store an instance of function in LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I need to store an instance of a function in the LocalStore, for example:

```
function boo() {
   //blah blah
}
var instance = new boo(); //I need to store this variable
```

How can I store `instance` variable in LocalStorage?

**Edit:**

Suppose I need to share same instance of an function in all browser's tabs/windows, just like singleton for all browser's tabs.

Comment: Your question implies the function will have some state. Are you using the module pattern or prototypical inheritance? You will need to serialize the resulting object to JSON and then place into localStorage.

Comment: your instance should be serializable for storage, and deserializable to reconstruct the instance again.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Suppose I need to share same instance of an function in all browser's tabs/windows.

Comment: @AfshinMehrabani [The local storage only stores strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#Storage). One way to convert objects into strings is via serialization to JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Attempting to store the function itself is unnecessary. The function is static code, not an instance of data and should be passed to the browser from your server.

Also, localStorage is separated by domain, so if your goal is to inject a function into a user's browser and then call it on other websites this is not possible. What you need for that is to create a browser plugin and submit it to the various stores.

The Javascript env per page is also not shared between tabs.

Answer (score -4):

what you can do is

```
var instance = this["boo"];
```

this will save the function but will leave out the context.
so you will have to save the context in some seperate variable or make the function independent of the context and save the `state` some where

to save whole of the context

```
var context = JSON.stringify(this);
now when you retrive it then just use eval
var context = eval(context);

instance.cal(context);
```

Comment: So it's actually is the function code, not the instance. Suppose I need to share same instance of an function in all browser's tabs/windows.

Comment: as i have said save the state of the context or the context itself. in some variable

Comment: Could you please add an example of saving the state of context?